# What does event BEX64 mean?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

Recently I had to deal with the situation where an application would crash with problem signature like:

```
Problem Event Name:BEX64
...
Fault Module Name:StackHash_1dc2
Fault Module Version:0.0.0.0
Fault Module Timestamp:00000000
Exception Offset:0000000000000000
Exception Code:c0000005
Exception Data:0000000000000008
OS Version:6.1.7600.2.0.0.274.10
```

There are some references that `BEX` stands for "Buffer Overflow Exception" and is somehow related to Data Execution Prevention.  Also the term "branch extended errors" is mentioned.  But not too much of specifics.  The best I could find is a brief mention in an example of DEP error signature in technet article:

> Indicates a buffer overflow (/GS) or DEP exception (BEX64 indicates a buffer overflow (/GS) or DEP exception on 64-bit versions of Windows)

Source: ["Data Execution Prevention"](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc738483(WS.10).aspx)

Hence, my question.  What is `BEX64`?  In which cases would an event with such name be produced?  Is there some list of all error signature codes?

---

*On a side note, the problem that I had turned out to be due to the AVX instruction set being available on CPU level, but not supported on OS level (Windows 2008 R2 RTM).  One of the DLLs being loaded used `msvcr120!log` function, which was calling one of AVX instructions, which led to crash.*